# detect which children has been clicked with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

i have a problem.
I have a script which load a single obj file, which have some children. I can change material and color for the children but I can't find a solution to detect the click on those child.

Actually I load the obj file this way:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load(percorso, function (object){
object.name = 'modello';
object.scale = (1,1,1);

//Scarica le immagini che si riflettono sull'anello
var loader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
loader.setCrossOrigin("");
loader.setPath( 'https://threejs.org/examples/textures/cube/pisa/' );
var textureCube = loader.load( [
  'px.png', 'nx.png',
  'py.png', 'ny.png',
  'pz.png', 'nz.png'
] );

var materiale_anello = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: colore_anello, envMap: textureCube, roughness: 0.5, metalness: 1});


console.log(object);
scene.add(object); //add model to scene
```

I hope you can give me some help!

Comment: Have a look at this [example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=interactive#webgl_interactive_cubes)

Comment: yeah man i've already seen that page but I don't know how to integrate that with my code, which load obj files and I need onclick event

Comment: `window.addEventListener("click", function_for_checking_the_intersecion);` Something like that. Or not for "click", but for "mousedown".

Comment: `three` modifies DOM and creates DOM elements. This means that DOM methods are available on those elements, including `addEventListener()`. It looks like you are asking for functionality to be added to something you currently have, which is quite a common request from people who are not actually programmers. You shouldn't ask for help here if you don't code yourself. If you don't have at least one coding attempt at the current request.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu i code myself but i'm not a pro in javascript, that's all. I've already tried adding an event listener but it didn-t worked so i came here, if you are here to answer my question it's ok, but if you came here just to say fact you can go away